# How to get the OS name for Amazon ec2 Linux instances

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am using aws-java-sdk api for collecting the all ec2 instances.
I able to collect the all instances but not able to get the OS name for Linux instances.
And getting the OS name with platform property for Windows instances.
Can any one help me about this.

Comment: have you tried `System.getProperty("os.name")` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using RunningInstance.Platform

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(); 
DescribeInstancesRequest req = new DescribeInstancesRequest(); 
List result = ec2.DescribeInstances(req).DescribeInstancesResult.Reservation;

        foreach (Amazon.EC2.Model.Reservation reservation in result)
        {
            foreach (Amazon.EC2.Model.RunningInstance runningInstance in reservation.RunningInstance)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(runningInstance.InstanceId);
                Console.WriteLine(runningInstance.InstanceType);
                Console.WriteLine(runningInstance.Platform);
            }
        }
```